# Trouble Adding Nearby Wikipedia Markers to Leaflet Map Using OpenCage Geocoding API

Tags: leaflet, google-maps-markers, geocoding

I'm working on a web project where I'm trying to add nearby Wikipedia markers to a Leaflet map based on geolocation data. I'm using the OpenCage Geocoding API to obtain latitude and longitude coordinates, and I'm trying to place markers on the map using the `fetchWikiMarkers` function.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
function getOpenCageCoordinates(address) {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'getOpenCage.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      address: address,
    },

    success: function(response) {
      const lat = response.results[0].geometry.lat;
      const lng = response.results[0].geometry.lng;

      fetchWikiMarkers(lat, lng);
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('Error fetching coordinates:', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    },
  });
}

const wikiFeatureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

const wikiIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'images/file-wikipedia-svg-logo-free-download-4.png',
  iconSize: [33, 33],
  iconAnchor: [32, 32],
});

function fetchWikiMarkers(lat, lng) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'wikiMarkers.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng,
    },

    success: function(response) {
      const geonames = response.data.geonames;

      geonames.forEach(function(geoname) {
        const marker = L.marker([geoname.lat, geoname.lng], { icon: wikiIcon }).addTo(map);

        const popUpContent = `
          <b>${geoname.title}</b><br>
          <p>${geoname.summary}</p><br>
          <a href="${geoname.wikipediaUrl}" target="_blank">Wikipedia Link</a>`;

        marker.bindPopup(popUpContent);
        marker.addTo(wikiFeatureGroup);
      });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('Error fetching Wiki Markers:', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    },
  });
}
```

While the above code works for fetching coordinates and placing markers, I'm having trouble integrating the `fetchWikiMarkers` function to display nearby Wikipedia markers. The markers do not appear on the map as expected.

I have verified that the `fetchWikiMarkers` function works correctly with manual coordinates. Could you please guide me on how to integrate the `fetchWikiMarkers` function properly into my code to display Wikipedia markers based on the coordinates obtained from the OpenCage Geocoding API?